# C# Modifying the list being iterated over using forEach

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, foreach

I would like to learn if it is possible to modify the list being iterated over using forEach so that there is no need to maintain an index.

```
var scanResults = await someFunction();
for (int i = 0; i < scanResults.Data.Count(); i++)
{
    if ((scanResults.Data.ToList()[i].Filters.Count() == 0) != (scanResults.Data.ToList()[i].SubscribedFilters.Count() == 0))
    {
        scanResults.Data.ToList()[i] = await AddFilters(scanResults.Data.ToList()[i]);
    }
}
return scanResults;
```

Comment: ofcourse you can . just use `foreach` instead of `for` loop

Comment: @NithinChandran I get that. But how would you use forEach in this case?

Comment: can u describe what is stopping you from using foreach

Comment: I'm modifying the same list I'm iterating over. Can you describe your idea with code?

Comment: @NithinChandran Right now I think that I need an index to do  that. Is there a way to not have to manage an index?

Comment: you can use for(;;;) loop if you are modifying the same list that you are iterating. foreach will give you an exception ONLY if you modify the same list (not the objects in the list) you are working with. Based on the code it seems unlikely to be the case. Did you try it out before posting the question?

Comment: Be aware that `scanResults.Data.ToList()` creates a new list from whatever `scanResults.Data` is. That is to say, it doesn't propagate the changes back to `scanResults.Data`. Also, by calling `.ToList()` so much, you're either introducing a smallish performance hit, or a major one, depending on if the code behind `scanResults.Data` is going off to the database or something to retrieve its results.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari Suppose I use forEach like `forEach(var item in scanResults.Data.ToList()` how would I change the code in the line having  `scanResults.Data.ToList()[i] = await AddFilters(scanResults.Data.ToList()[i]);`?. I'm unable to think of any other way other than having an index.

Comment: *scanResults.Data.ToList()[i]* The toList() is creating a new list (assuming this is from *System.Linq*) so that's not gonna give you an error. Sounds like a likely logic error though. If you saved *scanResults.Data.ToList()* into a variable and reused the same variable then now we are talking about the same list. In that case you would get an error.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari @John Regarding using `ToList()`, I seem to have overlooked that part. How do you suggest I change the code here?  I do need to creare a list to iterateover scanResults.Data.

Comment: If you want to not use extra memory better off sticking with for(;;) loop. Otherwise you may as well create a second list with the results. You could probably use some linq methods to generate a second list pretty easily or simply have a second list as a variable and update *scanResults.Data.ToList()[i] = await AddFilters(scanResults.Data.ToList()[i]);* above

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari Would be great if you could put these scenarios as an answer in code so that I can accept it and it'll be helpful for the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note as mentioned by John and myself in the comment that in your code you are using `ToList()` (presumably `System.Linq`) in the nested check and statements (which is likely a logical mistake); which means you are creating a new list each time. Assuming that you reference one list throughout your nested statement, you will run into `InvalidOperationException` with a message of **Collection Was Modified**.

### Scenario 1: Stick with `for(;;)` loop

The benefit of this is you don't need to use additional memory to create a temporary list or an alternative list.

### Scenario 2: `foreach` with a temporary duplicate list to modify

If you really insist on using `foreach` loop then one simple option is to create an identical list with the same data and iterate through that. Depending on what you are doing within the list this might not work. The downside with this approach is you are using additional memory to store the duplicate list.

Lots of the code is not given in the problem so we can't guarantee which would make more sense in your situation. However in most cases you would try to stick with the `for(;;)` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the rest of your code so I can only guess at the data types you are using but it'd be something like this.

```
foreach (var scanResult in ScanResults)
{
    if ((scanResult.Data.ToList().Filters.Count() == 0) != (scanResult.Data.ToList().SubscribedFilters.Count() == 0))
    {
        scanResult.Data.ToList() = await AddFilters(scanResult.Data.ToList());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can assign a value to a foreach iteration variable.

Comment: assign it to something else then and use that